# How do I solve for n (number of periods) in a loan repayment formula?

Tags: finance

[image]

Where

- A = payment Amount per period
- P = initial Principal (loan amount)
- r = interest rate per period
- n = total number of payments or periods

How can I rearrange the formula to solve for n?

Comment: Have you tried logarithms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$A = P \frac{r(1+r)^n}{(1+r)^n -1} \Rightarrow$$

$$A [(1+r)^n -1]= rP (1+r)^n \Rightarrow$$

$$(A-rP)(1+r)^n = A \Rightarrow$$

$$(1+r)^n = \frac{A}{A-rP}\Rightarrow$$

$$n = \log_{1+r} (\frac{A}{A-rP})$$

Comment: Thank you that is working great. I'm using this for a personal budget so that's all I need and I'm able to implement this now. However I don't completely understand how you got from step 2 to step 3 and I am curious. If possible could you elaborate on this?

Comment: @CalebMacdonaldBlack Step1: multiply left and right by $(1+r)^n -1$; step2: bring things from the right to the left and then bring the $-A$ to the right; step3: divide left and right by $A-rP$; step4: take the logarithm on left and right; where do you want an explanation?